# List switching slow and ripple effect lag

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, virtualscroll

I've been struggling for a (very long) while on performance issues on my app, that concern list switching with segment buttons.

I'm using virtual scroll to improve perfs, because a ngFor loop was insanely slow with only 200 elements.

In my template:

```html
  <ng-container *ngIf="currentList$ | async as currentList" class="full-height">

  <card-game-list
    [gameList]="currentList"
    [isWishList]="currentList.settings.url === 'wishlist'"
  ></card-game-list>
  </ng-container>

 </ion-content>
 <ion-footer >
  <ion-toolbar>
  <!-- LIST BUTTONS-->
  <ion-segment  *ngIf="boardGames.gameLists$ | async as lists" (ionChange)="selectList($event)">
    <ion-segment-button class="menuSegmentButton menuSegment{{list.settings.name}}"
                        *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index"
                      [value]="list.settings.name"
                        [class.segment-button-checked]="(currentList$ | async)?.settings.name === list.settings.name"
    >
      <ion-icon [name]="list.settings.iconUrl" class="ion-no-margin"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="small-margin-bottom">
        {{ list.settings.name }}
        <ion-badge>
          {{ list.filteredGamesCount$ | async }}
        </ion-badge>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Which gives this:
[image: Home Screenshot]

The custom component 'card-game-list' is basically a virtual scroll with ion-cards,I can give any needed code details.

The problems I have:
It take about half a second to swicth from a list to an other, when I click on a segment button, there's a short lag, then everything happens at the same time : the other list is displayed and the ripple effect occurs but in a laggy way.

The profiling shows this:
[image]

The Animation Frame Fired Takes allthe processing time (0.5s),I don't know iff that's supposed to work that way.

What I've tryied:

- Change Detection strategy to OnPush -> Improved the problem but still here
- All virtual scroll I could fing on npm (+ cdk) -> they all had their own unacceptable issues :'(
- Having much simplercomponent for the virtual scroll (card-game-list)-> didn't change anything

To go deeper:
What I think is it all have to do either with the way I switch lists,that is to say

```js
  public selectList($event) {
    const selectedList = $event.target.value;
    console.log(selectedList);
    this.boardGames.gameLists$.subscribe(lists => {
      this.listSubject.next(
        lists.find(list => list.settings.name === selectedList)
      );
    });
  }
```

Either with something wrong in my custom component...

I'm using RxJs observable to next the new list to the component,and I have the feeling
 that's not the best option.

So questions are:

1. Does it seems legit to use observable like this to switch lists?
2. Is there a way to call first the ripple animation (immediately) and then do the switching work?
3. Any other idea on how to improve this ?

Thanks for your help

Ionic infos

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\Piwi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.16.1 (C:\DEV\tools\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```